# How can i insert an element in the HTML BODY using Js then select the same element using Js and then append some more data into it?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I am trying to make a single page web app and i have different tabs example is **unapproved tab** . when i click on this tab i prevent the default using action using js then i get the container element of the page

```
let container = document.getElementById('container');
```

i then insert a table in the container

```
container.innerHTML = `
        <table id="table" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablebody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
        `;
```

once that is done i fetch some data using ajax and insert then into the table body using js.

```
     try {
        http.get('../includes/unapproved.inc.php')
            .then(res => {
                //check if the response if ok
                console.log(res);
                let rows = '';
                for (let i in res) {
                    rows += ` 
               <tr>
                    <td>${res[i].user_user_id} <td>
               <tr>
               `
                }
                tablebody.innerHTML = rows;
                console.log(table);

            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

    }
```

But when i try to insert the data i get this error

```
pages.js:51 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at pages.js:51
```

i do not understand why i am getting this error yet i have already inserted the table in the DOM.

below is the whole code

```
import { FETCH } from "./fetch.js";

export class PAGES {
    constructor() {
        this.unapproved = document.getElementById('unapproved');
    }
    events() {
        this.unapproved.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.unapprovedPage();

        })
    }
    unapprovedPage() {
        let container = document.getElementById('container');
        let table = document.getElementById('table');
        let tablebody = document.getElementById('tablebody');
        container.innerHTML = `
        <table id="table" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablebody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
        `;

        const http = new FETCH;

        try {
            http.get('../includes/unapproved.inc.php')
                .then(res => {
                    //check if the response if ok
                    console.log(res);
                    let rows = '';
                    for (let i in res) {
                        rows += ` 
                   <tr>
                        <td>${res[i].user_user_id} <td>
                   <tr>
                   `
                    }
                    tablebody.innerHTML = rows;
                    console.log(table);

                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: try declaring `tablebody` without `let`

Comment: You may want to provide correct closing tabs for table rows and data elements - the posted code appears to use opening tags twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting the `#tablebody` element before it is in the document. So the result will always be `null`.

First add the `innerHTML` content of the container element.

```
container.innerHTML = `
<table id="table" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tablebody">

    </tbody>
</table>
`;
```

And then select the element from the container using `querySelector`.

```
let tablebody = container.querySelector('#tablebody');
```

Also, prevent using ID's when appending dynamic content and instead use classes. Your page will not work as expected when there is more than one element with the same ID is on the page.

Comment: Thanks for it worked. Actually i realized it just some few minutes after posting the question. But i still have another similar problem where i was i am first loading the whole page using ajax then when i try to access some of the elements i have loaded  in the page i cannot access it using js. it sill comes null . am posting the code in a while

Answer (score 0):

in the example below i have an funtion **event**  that will listen for a button click then depending on the button clicked it will update the **location.hash**  when location.hash is changed i have a funtion somewhere that will load the **testdata** page  which has an empty table inside it and  insert the page content in the **main.page** . 
**this.unapprovedPage();**  function will then load some data from the server and feed the table that has now been loaded in the **mainpage** .

Everything works well but the problem is that when i click the respective button clicked very fast i get the error below or when i click it for the first time but when i click it for the second time all works well and the data is feed into the table

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at pages.js:47
```

How can i ensure that when the button is clicked the  data is only feed into the table only once the the **testdata** page has been loaded?

```
events() {
        this.unapproved.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            console.log('i have been clicked');
            e.preventDefault();
            location.hash = "testdata";
            this.unapprovedPage();


        })
    }
    unapprovedPage() {
        let table = document.getElementById('table');
        const http = new FETCH;

        try {
            http.get('../includes/unapproved.inc.php')
                .then(res => {
                    //check if the response if ok
                    console.log(res);
                    let rows = '';
                    for (let i in res) {
                        rows += ` 
                   <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>${res[i].user_user_id} </td>
                        <td>${res[i].user_user_id} </td>
                        <td>${res[i].user_user_id} </td>
                        <td>${res[i].user_user_id} </td>
                        <td>${res[i].user_user_id} </td>
                   </tr>
                   `
                    }
                    let tablebody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
                    tablebody.innerHTML = rows;
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#example').DataTable();
                    } );

                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please refrain from using this section for questions as this is for answers. Instead create a new question from the start so others can help you.

Comment: Thank you i have taken note